# Preflight Requests Getting Stuck In Middleware

Tags: javascript, cors

If I understand correctly, preflight requests cannot contain custom-headers.

I have some middleware that relies on custom headers.

```
router.use(function(req, res, next){
  var token = req.headers['x-access-token']
  if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
    next()
  } else {
    jwt.verify(token, 'secret', function(err, decoded) {      
      if (err) {
        console.log('err', err)
        next(err)
      } else {
        console.log('Decoded? ', decoded)
        req.decoded = decoded;    
        next();
      }
    });
  }
})
```

I feel like the above code is hacky because I'm matching the string of the request method, but OPTIONS get stuck in here because the token is undefined, as OPTIONS methods do not have custom headers.

My question is multi-parted:

1. Do preflight request run through all the middleware until the end-point is reached?
2. Is this an okay solution?  Essentially I'm bypassing CORS in the middleware, letting everything through and authenticating it on my own when the real request comes in.
3. If no to #2, how should I handle this?